# moodle - database connection failed when running a script

Tags: php, moodle

So I am setting up a moodle plugin that syncs groups defined in child courses into a meta course. I managed to install it based on the following instruction.

> Installation
>
> Copy the metagroups folder into your Moodle /local directory and visit
> your Admin Notification page to complete the installation.
>
> After installation you may need to synchronize existing meta-course groups, to do this run the cli/sync.php script (use the --help switch for further instructions on script usage).

So when i tried to run th sync.php script using this command in there terminal

```
php -f sync.php
```

it shows me an error message

[image]

I found that the line in the script that is causing this issue is the following line

> require_once(**DIR** . '/../../../config.php');

my config.php file looks like this:

[image]

I have no idea why this is happening, as all moodle functionality seems to be working, which means database connection is the way it should be. Does anyone know this is happening and a way around this. Thanks in advance.

By the way, my moodle version is 2.6.3 running in localhost on a mac OSX 10.9

Comment: Have you checked your mysql is running?

Comment: Yeah mysql is up and running. As I said, other moodle functionalities are working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but running moodle with MAMP.

The simple fix for me was just to add the php path for MAMP (for whichever PHP version I required):

```
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.40/bin/:$PATH
```

…and then run whatever PHP script I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess but I'm wondering if its picking up a different config.php

Try specifying the folder for the require_once

```
require_once('/Applications/XAMMP/moodlewebroot/config.php');
```

If that works then check the check the output of

```
echo DIR . '/../../../config.php'
```

Although it's more common to use dirname() in Moodle eg:

```
require_once(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))) . '/config.php');
```

Also some of the command line functions expect to have the dirroot set up in config.

```
$CFG->dirroot = '/Applications/XAMMP/moodlewebroot';
```